# While connecting to Oracle 12c DB facing error ORA-12543: TNS : destination host unreachable

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus, tns

I am able to connect to Oracle12C DB with with Oracle SQL Developer. but not able to connect with SQL Plus. with same credentials.
Why this is happening ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: what exactly are you running in `sqlplus` ?

Comment: you didn't show your actual 'sqlplus' command, with the specified connect string, which would provide important diagnostic information.  What did you discover while doing due diligence and googling 'ORA-12543'?

Comment: Also, `SYSDBA` is a role, not a user. You can't use it like that. Use `Enter user-name: SYS AS SYSDBA` or `Enter user-name: / AS SYSDBA` when prompted, or use `sqlplus username@db_service as sysdba` from the command line. See documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DE8A79BD-FAE4-4364-98FF-D2BD992A06E7.htm#ADMQS0361